# Rails 3.2 Bootstrap Tooltip reports ".tooltip() is not a function"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm using a combination of Rails 3.2.5 with bootstrap-sass gem. I've declared the following in application.js to ensure all js plugins are loaded.

```
//= require bootstrap
```

To double-check that inclusion succeeds I verify the html source of the page where I'm trying to make the tooltip appear:

```
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm trying to make either the tooltip or the popover work on any of the elements on my page. but I always get an error message (both from .js code in the project and when trying this manually from Firebug):

```
$('#navbar_foobar_link').tooltip();
TypeError: $("#navbar_foobar_link").tooltip is not a function
```

It doesn't look like the function is available from wherever I'm calling it, even though I'm able to find it under the Scripts tab in Firebug.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like it's got to be something obvious that I'm derping over.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing options to the tooltip function like

```
$('#element').tooltip('show')
```

Please check link and the provided options 
[Twiiterbootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)

Comment: I indeed have, with same results. The function is simply not in the namespace, and even Firebug doesn't suggest it's there with autocomplete.

Comment: Try adding the code in footer. it worked for me! for some reason it doesn't work in header!